# Consulta SQL Laravel ( Query a 3 tablas diferentes)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

no puedo optener la consulta que deseo y necesitaria la ayuda de ustedes.
Tengo tres tablas:Productos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla promoempresas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla promo_temp_products( tabla temporal)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me hace falta convinar el ID producto de las tres tablas, es decir llamar a los datos de los productos utilizando los otros ID de empresas y temp_productos.

Es mi consulta con Laravel:

```
  $table = DB::table('promoempresas')
        ->where('promoempresas.codigo',$idpromo)
        ->join('productos', 'productos.id', '=', 'promoempresas.idproducto')
        ->join('promo_temp_products', 'promo_temp_products.idproducto', '=', 'productos.id')
        ->get();
```

return $table;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado lo que puedes hacer es usar eloquent,primero que nada en la tabla productos de establecer las relaciones con las otras dos tablas ya sean 1 a 1 o 1 a muchos dependera de tu modelo, en el ejemplo a continuacion coloco hasmany que es 1 a muchos pero podria ser cualquier otro

```
public function promoempresas(){
      return hasmany(PromoEmpresas::class, 'idproducto');

}
public function promo_temp_products(){
          return hasmany(promo_temp_products::class, 'idproducto');
}
```

lo que coloque mas arriba debe ir en el modelo de producto,

luego en tu controlador en el metodo que requieres la informacion debes llamarlo de la siguiente manera

```
$productos = Productos::with('promoempresas','promo_temp_products');
```

para filtrar por id

```
$productos = Productos::with('promoempresas','promo_temp_products')->where('idproducto','=', $variable);
```

esto lo que hace cuando va a consultar la tabla productos automaticamente tambien va a buscar las relaciones a la tabla que definiste y de existir coincidencia te devolvera los datos, al ser eloquent cuando depures o hagas un dd() puedes observar donde dice "relations" que estaran como array las 2 tablas solo con los datos que esten asociados a la tabla o al id por el cual filtraste

para mas informacion puedes consultar aca  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score -1):

Otra solucion que encontre es:

```
    (SELECT  c.idproducto FROM productos P1 
 INNER JOIN promoempresas C
 ON P1.id = C.idproducto
 WHERE c.codigo = 'fgdsgsdgsdgh'
 GROUP BY P1.id)

UNION

(SELECT   cs.idproducto FROM productos P2 
 INNER JOIN promo_temp_products CS
 ON P2.id = CS.idproducto
 GROUP BY P2.id)




$query1 = DB::table('productos as P1')
      ->select('C.idproducto')
      ->join('promoempresas as C', 'P1.id', '=', 'C.idproducto')
      ->where('C.codigo', $idpromo)
      ->groupBy('P1.id');
    $query2 =
      DB::table('productos as P2')
      ->select('CS.idproducto')
      ->join('promo_temp_products  as CS', 'P2.id', '=', 'CS.idproducto')
      ->groupBy('P2.id')
      ->union($query1)
      ->get();
```